# Making ui.Select out of Feature Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to make items/list for `ui.Select` out of Feature Collection. I have developed a code, but I am receiving an error: [image].

```
var subset = borders.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GID_0', 'UZB'));    
var filtered = ee.List(subset.aggregate_array('NAME_1'));
print(filtered);    

  var provincename_select = ui.Select({
  items: filtered,

  onChange: function(value) {
    var provincename = value;
  },
  style: {width: '200px'}
  });

print(provincename_select);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f6005af7e1bd5bfe8e8a598fbb749fdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ui-elements need client side inputs:

```
// UI-elements need client side inputs:

// option 1: getInfo()
var filtClient = filtered.getInfo();
      var countryName_select = ui.Select({
      items: filtClient,

      onChange: function(value) {
        var provincename = value;
      },
      style: {width: '200px'}
      });

print(countryName_select);   


// option 2: use evaluate
filtered.evaluate(function(evaluatedList){
      var countryName_select = ui.Select({
      items: evaluatedList,

      onChange: function(value) {
        var provincename = value;
      },
      style: {width: '200px'}
      });

print(countryName_select);   
})
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9e1f87c785e2d15387e52476206fb41)  with a sample featureCollection as yours was not shared

Comment: Thanks your suggestion! Is it possible two filter/remove the duplicates from the list?

Comment: Use `distinct()` on a list [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/137ce9db638f6aaca8e4bae392728e85)